# Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route default is not defined

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, zend-route, zend-test

I'm trying to test a controller. Zend Tool has generated the following code:

```
class Default_CarrinhoControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{

public function setUp()
{
    $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
    parent::setUp();
}

public function testIndexAction()
{
    $params = array('action' => 'index', 'controller' => 'Carrinho', 'module' => 'default');
    $urlParams = $this->urlizeOptions($params);
    $url = $this->url($urlParams);
    $this->dispatch($url);

    // assertions
    $this->assertModule($urlParams['module']);
    $this->assertController($urlParams['controller']);
    $this->assertAction($urlParams['action']);
    $this->assertQueryContentContains(
        'div#view-content p',
        'View script for controller <b>' . $params['controller'] . '</b> and script/action name <b>' . $params['action'] . '</b>'
        );
   }
}
```

PHPUnit Bootstrap

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')         : 'testing'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
        get_include_path(),
    )));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
```

But it has failed and route is correct

```
 Default_CarrinhoControllerTest::testIndexAction()
 Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route default is not defined
 C:\xampp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Rewrite.php:318
 C:\xampp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Controller\Router\Rewrite.php:469
 C:\xampp\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\ControllerTestCase.php:1180
 C:\htdocs\farmaciaonline\FarmaciaOnlineWeb\tests\application\modules\default\controllers\CarrinhoControllerTest.php:16
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:939
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:801
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult.php:649
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php:748
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:772
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:745
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite.php:705
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:325
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:187
 C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:125
 C:\xampp\php\phpunit:44
```

I have the default phpunit generated bootstrap by zend tool, I've setted up some custom routes but the default routes are still working on the application. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is your project setup in a modular layout? Also isnt it `$this->view->url()` ?

Comment: @nav Yes it is modular. $this->url() it's the default, $this->view->url() return non-object error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like there's an [issue with the the Controller Test Case](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-11619) not setting the default route, if custom routes have been set (this is a different behavior than the framework).

The patch from the issue:

```
/**
 * URL Helper
 * 
 * @param array $urlOptions
 * @param string $name
 * @param bool $reset
 * @param bool $encode
 */
public function url($urlOptions = array(), $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true, $default = false)
{
    $frontController = $this->getFrontController();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter();
    if (!$router instanceof Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite) {
        throw new Exception('This url helper utility function only works when the router is of type Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite');
    }
    if ($default) {
        $router->addDefaultRoutes();
    }
    return $router->assemble($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode);
}
```

You'll need to pass `true` as the last argument when using the `url()` function.

Instead of patching the Test Case, you can just add the default routes someplace in the bootstrap process:

```
$frontController->getRouter()->addDefaultRoutes();
```

Comment: @Rafael Solved mine too - so I'm glad to share. Did you patch it, or just add the default routes in the bootstrap?

Comment: I've added the default routes. I will wait zendframework team solve the issue by applying the patch.

Comment: Adding `$router->addDefaultRoutes()` in the application bootstrap did the trick beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical problem you have not configured your app in the bootstrap properly and then invoking a request which leads to an undefined route. In your case the route is specified as `Route default`.

The route might be correct but just undefined.

For debugging purposes, output the `$url` you invoke so you see what's going on.

Comment: $url it's a empty array, How can i redfine all default routes so?

Comment: You need to setup the whole request logic for Zend Framework, so it feels well enough to run your controller. That's pretty awkward and non-trivial.