# Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route list_profile is not defined

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, router, socialengine

Note: i did try the answers listed in the following links but they did not work for me at all.

[Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: Route default is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765717/zend-controller-router-exception-route-default-is-not-defined)

[Zend_Controller_Router_Exception: "xyz" is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264834/zend-controller-router-exception-xyz-is-not-specified)

Hello, i have been trying to get this problem fixed myself for the last few days.. well it seems more like a week now (i'm new to most of this).

basically i am running Social Engine 4.2.4 with a plugin called "Listings / Catalog Showcase" and i cannot for the life of me fix the error i get when i search for any word(s) listed in any of the listings or the title of the listings.

the error occurs when a user searches any term from any listing in the search bar and stops all users from being able to get search results with words included in the listings.

here is the error log

```
    Error Code: ee9a2c
    exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'Route list_profile         is     not defined' in /mysite/public_html/application/libraries        /Zend/Controller/Router/Rewrite.php:310
     Stack trace:
     #0 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Router                /Rewrite.php(440):                         Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite->getRoute('list_profile')
     #1 /mysite/public_html/application/modules/List/Model/Album.php(35):                 Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite->assemble(Array,         'list_profile', true)
     #2 /mysite/public_html/application/modules/Core/views/scripts/search/index.tpl(44): List_Model_Album->getHref()
     #3 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/View.php(108): include('/mysite/public_html...')
     #4 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/View/Abstract.php(835): Zend_View->_run('/mysite/public_html...')
     #5 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(903): Zend_View_Abstract->render('search/index.tp...')
     #6 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(924): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('search/index.tp...', NULL)
     #7 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/ViewRenderer.php(963): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->render()
     #8 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php(277): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->postDispatch()
     #9 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(523): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->notifyPostDispatch()
     #10 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
     #11 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
     #12 /mysite/public_html/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
     #13 /mysite/public_html/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run()
     #14 /mysite/public_html/application/index.php(194): Engine_Application->run()
     #15 /mysite/public_html/index.php(24): include('/mysite/public_html...')
     #16 {main}
```

i have checked the files and it seems it is coming from the bootstrap.php file in the module's directory. however after 30 something re-writes done by me (my coding skills are very very basic on this) i still cannot figure out how to make it work so it will appear in the search results.

I did try to add a new code in the bootstrap.php file that i edited from a source online but it came back with the same results the code was/is.

```
    class list_Bootstrap extends Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract
     {
         protected function _initRouter(){
             $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
             $router = $fc->getRouter();
             $router->addRoute('list', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('listingitems/:listing_id', array('module' => 'list', 'controller' => 'index','action' => 'view')));

             return $router;
         }

      }
```

Comment: somewhere in your code you are using 'list_prrofille' route, but it is not defined. You need to define it similarly to: `$router->addRoute('list', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('listingitems/:listing_id', array('module' => 'list', 'controller' => 'index','action' => 'view')));` or not use it.

And it seems it is used here `modules/List/Model/Album.php(35):`

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem with routes from my own module.
The routes were declared in a manifest.php, but because of many braces I mistakenly put the 'routes' array inside the 'package' one, whereas they must be on the same level.